# Trouble with variable transformation over a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

> Consider the double integral over a region $D$
> $$\iint_D \cos\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right) \mathrm{dA}$$
> where $D$ is the triangular region in the $xy$-plane with vertices $\{(0, 0), (0, 1),
> (1, 0)\}$. Sketch the image of the region $D$ in the $uv$-plane under the variable transformation $u = x - y, v = x + y$ and evaluate the double integral using the new variables $u$ and $v$.

I found the new region $S$ to be a triangular region which represented an isosceles triangle with vertices at $(0,0), (0,2) \text{ and } (1,1)$. The variable transformation also meant that $ x = \frac{1}{2}(v+u)$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}(v-u)$. I know that $$\int\int f(x,y)  \text{dydx}$$ over a region $R$ also equals to $$\int\int f(x(u,v), y(u,v))\begin{vmatrix}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\\end{vmatrix}\text{dvdu}$$ over a region $S$.

By substituting in all the equations, I got:
$$\int _0 ^1 \int _u ^{-u+2} \frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\frac{u}v{}\right)\text{dvdu}$$
I changed the order of integration and got:
$$\int _0 ^2 \int _v ^{2-v} \frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\frac{u}v{}\right)\text{dudv}$$
which equals:
$$\frac{1}{2} \times \int _0 ^2 v(\sin \left(\frac{2-v}{v}\right) - \sin (1))\text{dv}$$
which I don't know how to simplify any further but I'm sure there is a rational answer. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Your transformation of the triangle is incorrect. The vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are fine, but $(0,2)$ is not right. The point $(x,y) = (0,1)$ becomes $(u,v) = (-1,1)$ under the transformation.

Comment: Also, the Jacobian determinant should be $2$, not $\frac{1}{2}$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bounds of integration are incorrect. Using the transformation, we have $(0,0)\to (0,0)$, $(0,1)\to (-1,1)$, $(1,0)\to (1,1)$. This is the region $-1\le u\le 1,|u|\le v\le 1$; since your substitution is linear, it is determined by three points. The Jacobian determinant is correct, as is the new integrand. So we have
$$
I=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{|u|}^1\cos\left(\frac{u}{v}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2}\;dvdu
$$Now change the order of integration and integrate:
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-v}^v\cos\left(\frac{u}{v}\right) \;dudv
=\int_{0}^{1} v\sin\left(1\right) \;dv=\frac{\sin(1)}{2}
$$